# Can onClick refresh the page?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table attached to Datasource that I would like to update every 30 seconds, or on widget onClick action. For some reason this isn't working.

```html
onAttach:

window.reloadId = setTimeout(function() { widget.datasource.load(); }, 2 * 60 * 1000);
onDetach:

clearTimeout(window.reloadId);
```

Comment: You should be using `setInterval()` instead of  `setTimeout()`

Comment: Probably be better to do onClick action of your widget if it is a button, otherwise you may be making a lot of unnecessary calls to refresh the datasource. Where is the onAttach event located, is it part of the page element or a widget within the page?

Comment: It's part of the page at the moment. I do have a PU that changes a record, and could use that to load the main table if it's better.

Comment: If there's a create button for example I would incorporate it into the button like so: `widget.datasource.createItem(function() { app.datasources.YourDatasource.load();});`

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Do you put that code in onAttach for the PU button or where?